# Insert json array to another based on key id using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Sorry for a noob question. I got two json that I need to merge. And I'm not really sure what operation/function to use in jq, so please enlighten me. Thanks!

color.json

```json
[{"id":1,"color":"red"},{"id":2,"color":"green"},{"id":3,"color":"blue"}]
```

shape.json

```json
[
  {
    "shape": "square",
    "color": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "red"
    },
    "texture": "smooth"
  },
  {
    "shape": "circle",
    "color": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "green"
    },
    "texture": "smooth"
  },
  {
    "shape": "triangle",
    "color": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "blue"
    },
    "texture": "smooth"
  },
  {
    "shape": "triangle",
    "color": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "blue"
    },
    "texture": "rough"
  }
]
```

Desired output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "square",
        "texture": "smooth"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "green",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "circle",
        "texture": "smooth"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "color": "blue",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "triangle",
        "texture": "smooth"
      },
      {
        "shape": "triangle",
        "texture": "rough"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried using `jq 'JOIN(INDEX(inputs[];.id);.[];.color.id | tostring;add)' shape.json color.json`. But it's not exactly what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Whats the idea behind `color.json`? All that info is already in `shape.json`?

Comment: Yeah but this is just the format. I basically need to add all shape values as a color object named 'shapes' if it has the same color id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `reduce`-based approach which simply iterates over the `shape.json` items, adding them to the `INDEX`ed object from `colors.json`. A final `map(.)` re-converts the object into an array:

```bash
jq '
  reduce input[] as $i (INDEX(.id);
    .[$i.color.id | tostring].shapes += [$i | {shape, texture}]
  ) | map(.)
' color.json shape.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "square",
        "texture": "smooth"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "green",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "circle",
        "texture": "smooth"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "color": "blue",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "triangle",
        "texture": "smooth"
      },
      {
        "shape": "triangle",
        "texture": "rough"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sZQ5z1_YBcx)